# iq-engines-sdk error : UnsatisfiedLinkError thrown while initializing com/iqengines/sdk/IQLocal

Tags: android, android-ndk, adt, windows-7-x64

I am trying to run an app on Android 4.2.2 that has a dependency on iq-engines-sdk

NDK is setup properly and has the following output after doing a project>clean

```
Gdbserver : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
Gdbsetup : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
Install : libiqengines-sdk.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libiqengines-sdk.so
Install : libiqindex.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libiqindex.so
```

I have the following files on iq-engines-sdk after the build

[image]

This was working before but now I get this error

```
W/dalvikvm(3867): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/iqengines/sdk/IQLocal;
D/AndroidRuntime(3867): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(3867): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e4b300)
E/AndroidRuntime(3867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(3867): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(3867):     at com.iqengines.sdk.IQE.initIqSdk(IQE.java:249)
E/AndroidRuntime(3867):     at com.iqengines.sdk.IQE.(IQE.java:224)
```

Do you know what is the cause of this? I have tried removing the projects on the workspace and importing them back , did a project clean and restarted my IDE to no avail.

Comment: Did you figure anything out? I'm having the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @EdwinEvans I was using an x86 AVD image , when you are using IQEngine you should use an armv7 AVD image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an x86 AVD image for IQEngine, make sure you use an armv7 AVD image